# how to save json string in a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a text field. I received string as below:

"value": "{\"airwayBills\":[\"84498761\"],\"dockets\":[\"1652395\"],\"error\":false,\"muditaError\":[{\"actionType\":\"docket\",\"docketNo\":\"1652395\",\"errorMessage\":\"No thing error\",\"pieceList\":null,\"quantity\":\"1\"}],\"muditaManifestExtra\":\"Unknown\",\"thingDetails\":[{\"airline\":\"Unknown\",\"bookingDate\":\"19-05-2014 13:03:15+0530\",\"currentPiecesDelivered\":\"0\",\"currentPiecesManifested\":\"1\",\"destination\":\"GOI\",\"flight\":\"Unknown\",\"inScannedPieces\":[],\"locationId\":\"MUDDELHUB1\",\"mode\":\"Air\",\"number\":\"1652395\",\"ordinality\":\"0\",\"origin\":\"DEL\",\"outScannedPieces\":[],\"quantity\":\"1\",\"recipientEmailId\":\"Unknown\",\"serviceProvider\":\"Unknown\",\"shipper\":\"Vector E Commerce Pvt. Ltd.\",\"thingType\":\"docket\",\"totPiecesManifested\":\"1\",\"totalPiecesDelivered\":\"0\",\"weight\":\"11\"}]}",

This value get stored correctly inside a field in the table, but when I try to fetch this value and save it in another field of another table then some of the values like "airwayBills\":[\"84498761\"] are stored as "airwayBills\":["0"], this is causing the loss of data. There is one more strange behaviour that this is happening randomly with only some of  the records. Some records are added correctly. For saving into another field I am just enclosing the string in a single quote to save the string as is.

Please help how to save it in a single field in Mysql. Please note that the above values are coming after a GROUP_CONCAT query on the first table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question but I need to save a string mentioned above in a mysql field

Comment: I get that, but if you cannot form a proper question with all the essential information (e.g. relevant code, valid input date) you cannot expect people here to give up their time trying to help you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the variable name $json_string as the one that contains your json in the give state (in your post), try [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes) before trying to insert it into the database.

Here's an extra question, are you building the json array manually using string concatenation or using php array and them json_encode ? (2nd one would make things easier for you, since when you need to add the json obtained after the first mentioned query ran you can just do json_encode and your done)